# Mean of elements from arbitrary number of nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

If I have a list, say:

```
foo =  [[4, 6, 2, 7], [1.2, 8.3, 9, 16]]
```

I can get the mean of each element as follows:

```
[(a + b) / 2 for a, b in zip(foo[0], foo[1])]
```

or

```
import statistics
[statistics.mean(i) for i in zip(foo[0], foo[1])]
```

How can I do the same with an arbitrary number of nested lists in `foo`?

I tried several things but they do not work, for example:

```
[statistics.mean(i) for i in zip(list(foo))]
```

I would strongly prefer to just use comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the work:

```py
[sum(i)/len(i) for i in zip(*foo)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any package:

```
[statistics.mean([foo[j][i] for j in range(len(foo))]) for i in range(len(foo[0]))]
```

With `numpy` it would be

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(foo)
means = np.mean(arr,axis=0)
```

**edit**

without *any* package:

```
[sum([foo[j][i] for j in range(len(foo))])/len(foo) for i in range(len(foo[0]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import statistics
foo =  [[4, 6, 2, 7], [1.2, 8.3, 9, 16]]
x = [statistics.mean(i) for i in zip(*foo)]
print(x)
```